# Manipulate a plot with display of a condition

Tags: plotting, manipulate

This is a how to question --- the example is without importance. I want to manipulate the plot of say a x^2 + b y^2  for (a,b)  belonging to a specific set, but a + b > 0. Is it possible to make appear the sum a+b at a specific position in the plot ?

Comment: Notihing I have no idea how to begin. I know how to  dispose two image side by side with Row but I don't know how to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting the answer based on taking the phrase "*the example is without importance*" on face value (i.e. not a homework or similar).

I am not exactly I understand the aim.

So, with these caveats and to motivate clarification:

```
f[a_, b_, x_, y_] := {a, b}.{x^2, y^2} /; a + b > 0
f[a_, b_, x_, y_] := Null
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Row[{"a+b= ", a + b}, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20}],
   Row[{ContourPlot[Evaluate@f[a, b, x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> 300],
     Plot3D[Evaluate@f[a, b, x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
      MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> {{0.1, 0.2, 0.5}}, 
      MeshStyle -> Red, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
      ImageSize -> 300]}]
   }, Alignment -> Center],
 {a, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {b, -1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nearly what I was expecting but  is it possible with a+b over the contour plot and if possible with --- Latex fonts

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki I am not sure whether you asking me a cosmetic change or if I misunderstand your aim. The contours are values of $a x^2+b y^2$. In either situation, I suggest you adapt the code above or just use it as a launching point for your own code. The best way to learn Mathematica is playing around. Good luck. :)

Comment: The only thing is that I want the condition inside the plot.